# Where to put profile test?

Tags: java, design, multithreading

I have an application with multiple threads that may be run on different hardware. To assist with tuning on different hardware I would like to create a "profiler" that can automatically run a fixed amount of data through using different numbers of threads.

I've thought of several ways of implementing this:

1. It's a test, so put it in with the unit tests
2. It's also a part of the app, so make it part of the top level class running the app
3. It's a helper, so create entirely new class `Profiler`

I'm leaning toward option 2, because I think it is simplest to implement and seems to fit in well. Anyone have any other ideas or comments?

Comment: Is this operating system specific or agnostic?  Because there are many OS specific tools that do this that you could include with your app.

Comment: It's Java - system agnostic

Answer (score 2):

IMHO I would lean towards option 3 as it allows you to keep your separation of concerns intact. In addition I would build out the profiler as its own entity so that it could get used across other projects/applications if need be.

While you shouldn't build for the unknown; building yourself into a corner via tight coupling is something you want to avoid as well.

Comment: +1: It's not a "test", since it's not a pass/fail situation.  It's not the main app.  It's another app in the package.